# Codeigniter - creating a function looping form with controller and method

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<form method="post" action="/scheduler/run">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Controller</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form-controller" />
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Method</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="form-method" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Seconds</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="form-seconds" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Loops</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="form-loops" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have this `form` data for scheduling, I wanted to run a `php` function which composed with `controller` and `method`, `seconds` is for how many seconds this works, and `loops` is how many times.

My attempt:

```
<?php
    class Scheduler extends CI_Controller {

        public function run()
        {
            $form_data = $this->input->post();

            for ($i=0;$i < $form_data['form-loops'];$i++) {
                $form_data['form-controller'].'/'.$form_data['form-method']; //run the function

                sleep($form_data['seconds']);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    class Scheduler extends CI_Controller {

        public function run()
        {
            $form_data = $this->input->post();

            for ($i=0;$i < $form_data['form-loops'];$i++) {
                $method = $form_data['form-controller'].'/'.$form_data['form-method']; //run the function
                $this->$method;
                sleep($form_data['seconds']);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```